how to load photo or video to Instagram feed composer - flutter
I'm trying to pass photos and videos to the Instagram app from the flutter based app. The Instagram app will receive this content and load it in the feed composer so the User can publish it to their Instagram Feed.
Instagram Sharing to Feed
I couldn't find a way to do it in flutter app. I need to specifically do it for IOS in flutter app. So far, I able to find out that it has to be done using Document Interaction API which is available in IOS
and this is the ios code that opens up Instagram feed composer with preloaded image or video
@IBAction func sharePhotoAsFeed(_ sender: Any) {
  guard let imageInstagram = UIImage(named: "photo.jpg") 
  else { return }
  let instagramURL = NSURL(string: "instagram://")
  if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(instagramURL! as URL) {
    let jpgPath = (NSTemporaryDirectory() as   
    NSString).appendingPathComponent("instagram.igo")
    do {
      try imageInstagram.jpegData(compressionQuality:
      0.75)?.write(to: URL(fileURLWithPath: jpgPath), options:
      .atomic)
    } catch {
      print(error) 
      return
    }
    let rect = CGRect.zero
    let fileURL = NSURL.fileURL(withPath: jpgPath)
    documentInteractionController =   
    UIDocumentInteractionController()
    documentInteractionController.url = fileURL
    documentInteractionController.delegate = self
    documentInteractionController.uti =
    "com.instagram.exclusivegram"
    documentInteractionController.presentOpenInMenu(from: rect, in:  
    self.view, animated: true)
 } else {
   print("Sorry the application is not installed")
 }
}

but I'm wondering how to achieve this in flutter app?
